# R dplyr join tables based on overlapping date time intervals

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, time

I have two tables, the `label` which contains the `label` time interval (start and end), and the `items` which have a unique timestamp for each `item`.

I want to map the `items` based on their timestamps. If the item timestamp falls within the `label`'s time interval, therefore the `item` belongs to that `label`.

For example these two `items` `a123`, `b682` are in the time interval which corresponds to `label` `X547`, so `a123`, `b682` belongs to `X547`

```
# Label, start - end time
have_label_start_end <- data.frame(label = c('X547', 'X285', 'X290')
                   , time = c(lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 9L, min = 58L, sec = 51, tz = "UTC"),
                              lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 10L, min = 4L, sec = 54, tz = "UTC"),
                              lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 11L, min = 8L, sec = 34, tz = "UTC"))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(start_time = time, stop_time = lead(time)) %>% dplyr::select(-time) 

> have_label_start_end
  label          start_time           stop_time
1  X547 2022-04-11 09:58:51 2022-04-11 10:04:54
2  X285 2022-04-11 10:04:54 2022-04-11 11:08:34
3  X290 2022-04-11 11:08:34                <NA>


# Item
have_item_time <- data.frame(item = c('a123', 'b682', 'c3324', 'd4343', 'e5343')
           , timestamp = c(lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 9L, min = 59L, sec = 34, tz = "UTC"),
                      lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 10L, min = 3L, sec = 13, tz = "UTC"),
                      lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 10L, min = 5L, sec = 17, tz = "UTC"),
                      lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 11L, min = 8L, sec = 35, tz = "UTC"),
                      lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 11L, min = 10L, sec = 09, tz = "UTC")))

> have_item_time
   item           timestamp
1  a123 2022-04-11 09:59:34
2  b682 2022-04-11 10:03:13
3 c3324 2022-04-11 10:05:17
4 d4343 2022-04-11 11:08:35
5 e5343 2022-04-11 11:10:09


# Map Items to Label
want <- data.frame(label = c('X547', 'X547','X285', 'X290', 'X290'),
                   item = c('a123', 'b682', 'c3324', 'd4343', 'e5343')
                   , timestamp = c(lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 9L, min = 59L, sec = 34, tz = "UTC"),
                              lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 10L, min = 3L, sec = 13, tz = "UTC"),
                              lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 10L, min = 5L, sec = 17, tz = "UTC"),
                              lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 11L, min = 8L, sec = 35, tz = "UTC"),
                              lubridate::make_datetime(year = 2022L, month = 4L, day = 11L, hour = 11L, min = 10L, sec = 09, tz = "UTC")))


> want
  label  item           timestamp
1  X547  a123 2022-04-11 09:59:34
2  X547  b682 2022-04-11 10:03:13
3  X285 c3324 2022-04-11 10:05:17
4  X290 d4343 2022-04-11 11:08:35
5  X290 e5343 2022-04-11 11:10:09
```

Comment: Can we assume that the label times never overlap, ie only one label can ever apply?

Comment: @JonSpring good question. As per my example, where the subsequent label defines the stop time for the precedent label. For example, label A ends when label B starts. So the last label technically has no stop time because it's not succeeded with another label. But in practice, each label has a known average duration, so I'm ok if the stop time of the last label is just its start time plus the average duration of the labels.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that converts the intervals to a start and end row, adds the item_time table, and then fills the labels from those intervals to populate the item_time table.

```
library(tidyverse)
have_label_start_end %>%
  pivot_longer(-label, values_to = "timestamp") %>%
  bind_rows(have_item_time) %>%
  arrange(timestamp) %>%
  fill(label, .direction = "down") %>%
  filter(!is.na(item)) %>%
  select(label, item, timestamp)
```

This assumes every item is within one and only one interval. If it's possible that an item could be outside of any intervals, or in more than one, we'd need to revise this.

---

Another approach could be to use the `fuzzyjoin` package, which accommodates "non-equi" joins like this (as do `data.table` and `sqldf`). One tweak is that we need to replace any `NA` stop_times with a valid timestamp. In this case we can use the max from `have_item_time`.

Here, we get all the matches where the specific timestamp in `have_item_time` is between (inclusive) any of the intervals in `have_label_start_end`.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
have_item_time %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(have_label_start_end %>%
                    replace_na(list(stop_time = max(have_item_time$timestamp))), 
                  by = c("timestamp" = "start_time",
                         "timestamp" = "stop_time"),
                  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`))
```

Comment: Each `item` belongs strictly to one `label`, meaning it should belong to one `label` only at a time. But I appreciate the second approach as well, which will help to identify errors. Also thank you for the first solution, especially the `bind_rows + fill(down)` step, it's more simple than I thought!

Comment: I guess you could even simplify further and just commingle the start_times with the timestamps, sort, and fill down the labels.

Answer (score 1):

We can use {powerjoin} :

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(
  have_item_time, have_label_start_end, 
  by = ~.x$timestamp > .y$start_time & 
    (.x$timestamp < .y$stop_time | is.na(.y$stop_time)),
  keep = "left")
#>    item           timestamp label
#> 1  a123 2022-04-11 09:59:34  X547
#> 2  b682 2022-04-11 10:03:13  X547
#> 3 c3324 2022-04-11 10:05:17  X285
#> 4 d4343 2022-04-11 11:08:35  X290
#> 5 e5343 2022-04-11 11:10:09  X290
```